# Completely schematic construction?

Tags: terminology, dependency-grammar, cognitive-linguistics

I'm trying to understand what is a completely schematic construction in cognitive grammar.
I found an example: VP --> V NP

So, is that a construction that can be easily described by a general rule and where you have the freedom to replace a lexical item by another one of the same category?

Comment: If you use only arbitrary symbols, you are describing the construction by a general rule. What that rule is, and what it means is not clear, but any symbol divorced from real data can be described as "completely schematic", I suppose, though that's not a standard description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A schematic construction in CG is one with a very general meaning and with free slots that can be filled with lexemes compatible with it. A canonical case is the English Ditransitive Construction S OBJ1 OBJ2 whose sense is intended or successful transfer, as in "John gave Peter a book". As you see, the sense is kept very general in order to also accommodate less prototypical instances such as "She promised me a nice surprise".